# Memory leaks on iOS6 converting std::map to NSDictionary

Tags: c++, ios, ios6, objective-c++

I am writing a method to convert C++ `std::map<std::string,std::string>` to `NSDictionary` as below:

```
NSDictionary* NSDictionaryFromMap(const StringMap& map){
    NSMutableDictionary * dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    NSLog(@"NSDictonaryFromMap() - size:%d", (int)map.size());

    for (auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); it++){
        NSString * key = (0 == it->first.length())?(@""):(@(it->first.c_str()));
        NSString * value = (0 == it->second.length())?(@""):(@(it->second.c_str()));

        [dict setObject:value forKey:key];
        NSLog(@"NSDictonaryFromMap() - key:%@ value:%@", key, value);
    }

    NSDictionary * nd = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict];
    dict = NULL;

    NSLog(@"NSDictonaryFromMap() - dictionary:%@", nd);
    return nd;
}
```

But I got some memory leaks when calling this method. Sorry I cannot post image here. In instrument, it highlights memory leaks on four function calls

```
NSMutableDictionary * dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSString * key = (0 == it->first.length())?(@""):(@(it->first.c_str()));
NSString * value = (0 == it->second.length())?(@""):(@(it->second.c_str()));
[dict setObject:value forKey:key];
```

On iOS 7 and iOS 8, there is not any memory leaks, but on iOS 6,  it had.
How to fix those leaks for iOS6?

I also posted this issue in Apple Forum:
https://devforums.apple.com/message/1114878#1114878

Comment: For object pointers you should use `nil` instead of `NULL`

Comment: I'm having the same issue with conversion of std::map to NSMutableDictionary... did you find out what's the problem, perhaps you can post your solution.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've said, it seems like the returned dictionary is being leaked.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know iOS so much, but i see you are using

```
NSString * key = (0 == it->first.length())?(@""):(@(it->first.c_str()));
NSString * value = (0 == it->second.length())?(@""):(@(it->second.c_str()));
```

but don't see where release it.
For each loop it will create 2 pointer and don't release it.
I don't know my opinion right or not, but i only see there. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Using ARC with Objective-C does not require you to release the variables.